# Can I travel from the US to India via Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, indian-citizens

I am an Indian passport holder holding valid US work visa and Canadian tourism visa. Can I travel to India via Toronto and back to the USA via Toronto ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that.  Tourist visas are valid for transit in every case of which I am aware (UK, Schengen, US, Canada).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to find an official source to confirm this.

Answer (score -4):

of course you can. You can transit anywhere if you have a valid ticket and a route to your destination and the departure city.

Comment: That's not at all true. Some countries (eg the USA) or Airports/airport combinations require passing local immigration even when transiting. Some countries require a visa for certain nationals even if they wil not leave the international area of an airport.